# How to get the products in a category thats based on Dynamic Product Groups from the shopware API

Tags: shopware6

I have a high volume shop with a lot of products and categories.
The products are seasonal, so a lot of new products are added.

Because of this, dynamic product groups are perfect.  We set conditions and add the group to the category.

Right now i'm trying to get all the products of the category in the api's (both backend and store), but i dont get any product back. I do get a `streamId` back in the store-api `https://localhost//store-api/product-listing/9cf2c65bd7084144aa4d4a35bb3f568e`  But there is no endpoint i can call for the `streamId`.

Next to that, the breadcrumbs are also missing on the front-end.

What is the best way to get a the products from a category back in the API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do have the `id` of the `product_stream` you can filter `product` entities by them having that `id` as part of their `streamIds`:

```js
// POST /api/search-ids/product
{
    "page": 1,
    "limit": 500,
    "filter": [
        { 
            "type": "equalsAny", 
            "field": "streamIds", 
            "value": [
                "65103ca79e1e4e3ba846f551fbb1cb36" // your product stream id
            ] 
        }    
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to add an association, and get the products in the same response?